# How to change Bootstrap spinners' color to other than text color utilities?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, colors

I included a Bootstrap-4 spinner (as described here ) in a web page, but it seems that only the colors from text color utilites can be used (primary,warning, success...), which is quite limited.
I would like to be able to change the theme of the webpage, and therefore the color of the spinner too, to a color that is not one of the text color utilites.
Is it possible to do that and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well one thing you can do is,

```
<div class="spinner-border" role="status" style="color: darkgreen">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but the color was overwritten because i did let  the text-light class. I just removed it and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of [bootstrap spinner](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/) to any of your favourite color. You just need to set the `color` property of the spinner.

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
.text-blue {
  color: blue;
}
.text-orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="spinner-border text-red" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>

<div class="spinner-border text-blue" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>

<div class="spinner-border text-orange" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```